# Vertical subcaption beside horizontal subfigure

Tags: vertical-alignment, captions, subfloats, subcaption, floatrow

I have a very specific problem:
I need two or three subfigures placed under each other. I want to have one main caption for both of them and a subcaption for each one. Because the pictures are pretty large and the space is limited, I want the subcaptions to be on the left side of the subfigures and being vertical while the picture itself stays horizontal.

I was already able to get the subfigures under each other with a caption on their left side using the subfig and floatrow package (see the code below)

My current problem is that whatever caption I enter in the \sidesubfloat commands, it is not displayed and I have no idea how to get it to be displayed vertically.

I know this problem is very specific and very complex, but maybe someone knows how to achieve it.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=center}

...

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfloatrow*}
        \sidesubfloat[]{
            \label{fig:XiParameterCuts0}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Preliminary/XiParameter_Cuts0.png}
        }
    \end{subfloatrow*}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \begin{subfloatrow*}
        \sidesubfloat[]{
            \label{fig:XiParameterCuts3}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Preliminary/XiParameter_Cuts3.png}
        }
    \end{subfloatrow*}
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \caption{Topologieparameterverteilungen thermischer \textXi\textsuperscript{--} Hyperonen - simulierte Signale (grün) und kombinatorischer Untergrund (rot) - ohne (\ref{fig:XiParameterCuts0}) und mit (\ref{fig:XiParameterCuts3}) Precuts (schwarze Linien) \todo{Neue Bilder}}
    \label{fig:XiParameter}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I can show you how to do it without using floatrow or subfig.  How to do it WITH those packages is harder.

Comment: OK, at least the comments work now, thanks for the help, somehow the site cretaed two acoounts for me. Anyway: I do not have to use the floatrow or subfib package, it was just the only way I could find to achieve what I was looking for. If there are better packages that look the same way, I would be happy to get to know them.

Comment: A full MWE would be useful.  I don't know what package \textXi comes from.

Comment: I don't know what MWE stands for, but \textXi comes from the package textgreek, its nothing special, I just use it to get the Unicode characters for greek letters outside of a math area, because I want the font of the greek characters to match the font of the rest of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution places the `\subcaption` in the upper left corner and rotates it 90 degrees.

Note: Because `\subcaption` is in a `minipage` and the image isn't, one must place any `\label` inside the caption argument.  (`\refstepcounter` defines macros used by `\label` which will be lost at the end of the `minipage`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\ULsubfloat}[2][\empty]% #1 = caption (optional), #2 = image
{\hbox{% unbreakable group
  \sbox0{#2}% measure height of image
  \captionsetup{position=top, justification=raggedleft, singlelinecheck=false}%
  \rotatebox[origin=bl]{90}{\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0}
    \subcaption{#1}
  \end{minipage}}\raisebox{\dp0}{\usebox0}%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \ULsubfloat[some text here\label{fig:XiParameterCuts0}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    }
    \vspace{10pt}
    \ULsubfloat[\label{fig:XiParameterCuts3}]{%
       \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
    }
    \caption{Topologieparameterverteilungen thermischer \textsuperscript{--} Hyperonen - simulierte Signale (grün) und kombinatorischer Untergrund (rot) - ohne (\ref{fig:XiParameterCuts0}) und mit (\ref{fig:XiParameterCuts3}) Precuts (schwarze Linien)}
    \label{fig:XiParameter}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks, works like a charm!!!
I just changed it to justification=centering in the \captionsetup, so that its not at the top, but centered.