# Row- and Column-specific labels for subfigures

Tags: captions, titles, subcaption

I am trying to build something akin to the below, where each column and each row has one title/label.
How can I achieve it? Maybe with the use of `subcaption`, but I cannot find the solution. I am assuming that the plots are already built individually (e.g. in R) and only need to be put together in TeX. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399638/vertical-subcaption-beside-horizontal-subfigure) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228436/subfigures-caption-for-every-row-and-every-column) are part of the solution, but cannot figure out how to put the column titles on top rather than bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the solution below. In the code:

- `\adjustboxset` from `adjustbox` applies settings globally to each image or locally within an environment
- `valign=c`, an extra key from `adjustbox`, sets an image baseline in the middle point
- `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` from `cellspace` force a minimum space between rows in its own column types `S{x}`, where `x` can be `l`, `c`, `r`, `p{...}` or any regular column type
- `\multicolmn` cancels the effect from `S{x}` in a header.

In order for `\adjustbox` to work in this example, optional `[Export]` is required.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cellspace}

\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{0pt}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}S{p{#1}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
  \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth,valign=c}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{1.0\linewidth}{@{}
      l
      X @{\hspace{6pt}}
      X
    @{}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1994}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2007}} \\
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Risk score}}
    & \includegraphics{example-image}
    & \includegraphics{example-image} \\
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Caseload size}}
    & \includegraphics{example-image}
    & \includegraphics{example-image}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like a neat solution, and it improves on mine in that column labels are precisely centred (mine are a bit off). However, my output after implementing you code looks quite bad. The figures are too big and overlap across columns. The labels are out of centre as well, because of the oversizing, I think. What could I be missing?

Comment: I think adding "[Export]" before {adjustbox} fixed it, although I wouldn't have thought so. Anyhow, it works. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, yes `[Export]` is the one that makes all this MWE work! I didn't think you would miss it. I'm glad it works.

Comment: Could you please just indicate how to generalise this solution to a 3x2 case (where there are 3 rows of figures and 2 columns)? I am new to tabularx and am struggling with it

Comment: Of course. Simply duplicate the second row and append a row separator **\\** at the end of the second row. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228436/subfigures-caption-for-every-row-and-every-column), I just moved the column captions from the bottom of their subfigure space to the top. This is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand\myrowlabel[1]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.30\textwidth}\raggedleft
    \caption{model A}
    \myrowlabel{$R=1$}
    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {example-image-a}}\\
    \myrowlabel{$R=2$}
    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {example-image-a}}\\
    \myrowlabel{$R=3$}
    \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {example-image-a}}
\end{subfigure}%
\hspace{1em}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.30\textwidth}\raggedleft
    \caption{model B}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]  
    {example-image-b}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {example-image-b}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.30\textwidth}\centering
    \caption{model C}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]  
    {example-image-c}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {example-image-c}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]
    {example-image-c}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Grid test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```